# Can't use mouse and touchpad after wake up

Tags: suspend, pantheon, touchpad, mouse

Elementary OS 5.1.7
Laptop: dell inspiron 7559

Nvidia graphics is disable
`Kernel driver in use: i915`

After my laptop wake up Pantheon refuse to respond on left click (touchpad doesn't work too). I can't use GUI, so I need to write
`sudo service lightdm restart` to restart my session.

I already tried to change mouse, but nothing changed.

YT link: https://youtu.be/z90Wd-DZQvI